# Django Registration with Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, django-registration

So I am using a custom user model **accounts.player** and i'm also using **django-registration** in my project.

With the custom model it now encounters an error. I know I could just write my own registration code but is there a way to use the custom model class with django-registration. I had a look on the docs but didn't really find a solution.

I'm sure theres probably a way using something like a subclass but i'm not sure how to implement this.

What files are required and what code would I need??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for a personal project of mine:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'MoreAboutUser', unique=True)
    age = ....
    gender = ....
```

Regarding your error, I don't know how to help you since you didn't provide any traceback/code. But you can connect your custom model with the User model with a OneToOneFiel'

Answer (score 0):

You could either **Fork django-registration and make changes** to Make it work with Custom User model... But that would be a long process...

Or

You could **switch to [django-allauth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-allauth)** , which is a **better and well maintained Registration app** for Django. 
It is compatible with Latest django version and also provides social registration out of the box